# handle multiple selenium tests at a time with discord.py

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver, discord.py

I created a discord bot using discord.py 2.0, which on a slash command will run a chromedriver and selenium instance on a Debian server.
When a user types `/selenium <link>` on a discord server the bot runs a function in python which handles the selenium automated test. My problem is that I want to be able to do multiple tests at a time. On the first time when I run the command, the bot responds `Successfully ran a selenium test`, but on the second time it is like in the image:[image: error on running selenium].

This is some of my code:

```
class aclient(discord.Client):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__(intents=discord.Intents.default())
        self.synced = False

    async def on_ready(self):
        await self.wait_until_ready()
        if not self.synced:
            await tree.sync(guild = discord.Object(id = xxxxxxxxxxxxxx))
            self.synced = True
        print(f"The bot has logged in as {self.user}.")

async def selenium_py(url):
    # selenium test...

client = aclient()
tree = app_commands.CommandTree(client)

@tree.command(name="selenium", description="run a selenium test", guild=discord.Object(id=729380155734228994))
async def self(interaction: discord.Interaction, url: str):
    await interaction.response.send_message("Successfully ran a selenium test", ephemeral=True)

    driver = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path=ChromeDriverManager().install())
    driver.maximize_window()

    driver.get(url)

    await selenium_py(url)

client.run('bot token')
```

Imports:

```
import discord
from discord import app_commands

from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from webdriver_manager.chrome import ChromeDriverManager
```

How can I run multiple selenium tests at a time using the bot?

Comment: Does this help?: https://stackoverflow.com/a/72539698/16136190

Comment: @TheAmateurCoder I don't want to edit any message here